# Can I create my own template to scaffold my own WebAPI controller when using WebAPI 2 and VS 2013 RC Update 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

I tried to use the scaffolding but there are so many changes I need to make for it to meet my needs. Is there some way I can make my own template so I can scaffold my own controller automatically.

Please note I just updated to the latest release of VS2013 RC Update 2. Not sure if there is any new functionality in that which would help me.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that customs scaffolders are supported:

1. Write a new scaffolder as a VSIX extension.  This will be available for any project on your machine, but does require installing the VSIX to share.  A sample walkthough is provided [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/03/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio.aspx)
2. Customize the scaffolding T4 templates for your project.  This will be available only in the project where you do it, but should not require any further custom installation once it's there (note: setting it is simplified by having the [SideWaffle](http://sidewaffle.com/) extension installed).  A sample walkthrough can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/02/10484865.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Never done it before, but this may help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/03/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio.aspx